# Show folderpath in Outlook search result

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is there a way to add a column to the search result in outlook, that shows the folderpath instead of only the folders name? If yes, may you provide some tutorials or documentation?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information, one email at a time with this.

http://vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=65&cmd=showitem

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim Msg$
  Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
  If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
  Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
  End If
  Set F = obj.Parent
  Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
  Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
  If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
  End If
End Sub
```